# Oracle Date datatype error

Tags: sql, database, oracle, oracle10g, oracle9i

I m little bugged with Oracle

That my SQL below

```
select * from orders where 
trunc(ordered_date)
between
to_date('01-JAN-12') 
and 
to_date('07-JAN-12')
```

Ordered_date is DATE datatype

Is it giving the below error.

```
Error starting at line 1 in command:
select * from orders
where 
trunc(ordered_date)
between 
to_date('01-JAN-12') 
and 
to_date('07-JAN-12')
Error report:
SQL Error: ORA-01841: (full) year must be between -4713 and +9999, and not be 0
01841. 00000 -  "(full) year must be between -4713 and +9999, and not be 0"
*Cause:    Illegal year entered
*Action:   Input year in the specified range
```

I'm confused what is causing this error in mu code.

Any inputs would be great.

Thanks !!!

Comment: Please run this: `SELECT TO_CHAR(ordered_date,'YYYY') FROM orders` and post the results.

Answer (score 1):

You have to specified the date format.

Add a parameter to to_date function :

```
 to_date('01-JAN-12', 'DD-Mon-YY')
```

Hope it's helps.

Regards.

Comment: Thanks for your input. But the issue still persists.

Comment: @user1141584 - Can you update your question to show the error you're getting when you specify the format mask?

Answer (score 0):

If you're really using date literals, you can use this syntax instead:

```
select * from orders where 
trunc(ordered_date)
between
date '2012-01-01'
and
date '2012-01-07'
```

Comment: Thanks Jeffrey , the issue still persists

Comment: So you still get `ORA-01841` with this modified query? Are you sure you're not getting a different error?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should convert both the dates, i.e DB date and the 2 input dates, into the same format, like this

```
SELECT *
  FROM ORDERS O
 WHERE TO_DATE(TO_CHAR(O.ORDERED_DATE, 'DD-MON-YY'), 'DD-MON-YY') BETWEEN
       TO_DATE('01-JAN-12', 'DD-MON-YY') AND
       TO_DATE('07-JAN-12', 'DD-MON-YY')
```

Hope it helps